# How to use a file to migrate data from mysql to a clickhouse?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, clickhouse

I need to migrate the data from Mysql to ClickHouse and do some testing. These two database networks are not working, I have to use files to transfer. The first thing I think of is that I can use the mysqldump tool to export .sql files.

mysqldump -t -h192.168.212.128 -P3306 --default-character-set=utf8 -uroot -proot database_name table_name > test.sql

Then I found that there are 120 million pieces of data in the mysql table. The insert statement of the .sql file exported in this way is very long. How to avoid this situation, such as exporting 1000 data each time as an insert statement ?

In addition, this .sql file is too big, can it be divided into small files, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump has an option to turn on or off using multi-value inserts. You can do either of the following according to which you prefer:

Separate Insert statements per value:

```
mysqldump -t -h192.168.212.128 -P3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-extended-insert -uroot -proot database_name table_name > test.sql
```

Multi-value insert statements:

```
mysqldump -t -h192.168.212.128 -P3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --extended-insert -uroot -proot database_name table_name > test.sql
```

So what you can do is dump the schema first with the following:

```
mysqldump -t -h192.168.212.128 -P3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --no-data -uroot -proot database_name > dbschema.sql
```

Then dump the data as individual insert statements by themselves:

```
mysqldump -t -h192.168.212.128 -P3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-extended-insert --no-create-info -uroot -proot database_name table_name > test.sql
```

You can then split the INSERT file into as many pieces as possible. If you're on UNIX use the split command, for example.

And if you're worried about how long the import takes you might also want to add the --disable-keys option to speed up inserts as well..

BUT my recommendation is not to worry about this so much. mysqldump should not exceed MySQL's ability to import in a single statement and it should run faster than individual inserts. As to file size, one nice thing about SQL is that it compresses beautifully. That multi-gigabyte SQL dump will turn into a nicely compact gzip or bzip or zip file.

EDIT: If you really want to adjust the amount of values per insert in a multi-value insert dump, you can add the --max_allowed_packet option. E.g. --max_allowed_packet=24M . Packet size determines the size of a single data packet (e.g. an insert) so if you set it low enough it should reduce the number of values per insert. Still, I'd try it as is before you start messing with that.

Answer (score 0):

clickhouse-client --host="localhost" --port="9000" --max_threads="1"  --query="INSERT INTO database_name.table_name FORMAT Native" < clickhouse_dump.sql